Recover PDF comments when Adobe Acrobat Reader has frozen
While editing a .pdf file adding comments, my Adobe Acrobat Reader (version 2024.003.20180) suddenly froze and after a while all the pages turned white. I could only see my comments, saving didn't work (failed to save, a number was out of range), and it seems my work the past few hours is lost. Is there any way to save these comments although the PDF reader has soft crashed?

In the right sidebar, open the comments tab and click the three dots. Select "Export all to data file" and save the .fdf file. Next, close Acrobat Reader and open the .pdf file again (the comments will be gone). Finally you can import the comments again using "Import data file" in the same menu where you did the export to import the .fdf file.

